# Eclipse export SpotBugs configuration to xml-file

Tags: eclipse, maven, findbugs, spotbugs

Is it possible to export a SpotBugs configuration

[image]

to an XML file which you can use for Maven, like [described here](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html)?

If yes, how can you do this?